# Cant find the Gmaps API in CodeIgniter Environment

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good Day to you,

I have a difficulty in finding the google maps api key. I had to change the base_url in the config file and since then it gives me this error:

Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.ab @ js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-USA:32
        util.js:211

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
        util.js:211 
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

if i add this tag with my api key into the `<head>` of the page: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>`

i get this error:

[image] unfortunately i only have an img of the error right now.

first it was missing then it was duplicated. and why would it be missing if i change the config?i know that you have to get a new api key with the new domain and i did that but there is a conflict with the old api key which i cant find anywhere. where then would i find the original key? i tried searching in all the files couldnt find any key. does somebody have a hint for me? i tried searching all files for "googleapis.com". Maybe the there is an otherway to link to the google api of which i dont know. im really looking forward to get this fixed.

thank you for your time to read this and i hope someone can help me

regards
theweeezel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error stated :

> The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a *key* parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a *client* parameter with your client ID or a *key* parameter with a valid API key.

If you will check the guide to [API keys and client IDs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). Kindly double check the API Key created and follow the script tag below.

> If you're using the API under the standard plan, you must use a browser key (a type of API key) set up in a project of your choice.
>
> ## Specify a key when loading the API
>
> To specify a key, include it as the value of a `key` parameter when loading the API.
>
> For example:

## NOTE:

> Google Maps APIs are available for Android or iOS apps, Web browsers, and via HTTP web services. APIs in each platform require a specific type of key. *The Google Maps JavaScript API will only work with a Browser key*. APIs of the same platform can use the same key.

Hope this helps.